# How can I add a "Total" label to a numerical column?

Tags: sql

I am  trying to create a query which outputs data like so:

[image]

This is what  I currently have but it turns out that you can't have letters in a numerically set column. Is there a way to do this using the UNION method or is the way to do it complicated?

```
SELECT HIRE_ID, AMOUNT
FROM HIRE_CHARGE, HIRE
WHERE HIRE.CHARGE_ID = HIRE_CHARGE.CHARGE_ID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Total Amount:', SUM(AMOUNT) FROM HIRE_CHARGE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the value to a string.  Something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(HIRE_ID AS VARCHAR(255)), AMOUNT
FROM HIRE_CHARGE HC JOIN
     HIRE H
     ON H.CHARGE_ID = HC.CHARGE_ID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Total Amount:', SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM HIRE_CHARGE;
```

And learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you for your answer it has helped greatly. I will learn to join correctly but at the moment this is what is required. Thanks!